# change python 3.7.2 to 3.7.1 in windows

Tags: python

currently I am using python 3.7.2 ,I want to to change my python version with 
3.7.1 ,I want only 3.7.1 not both how can I do that without changing settings 
of environment variables .I have pip installed in my pc.

I have searched on many blog but they were regarding using multiple python version.

My main target is to install python vs 3.7.1 with Django 2.1.5

Comment: Dare I ask why you want to downgrade your python? And why you can't just uninstall the old version, and then install the new version?

Comment: Once you get this sorted out you should really look into using virtual environments.

Comment: some people are saying I am going to mess up with  my python environment setting

Comment: I agree with @Reez0, using `virtualenv` would be the sensible way to manage the two versions you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you  can specify python version when running things:

```
py -3 setup.py # run latest Python 3
py -2 setup.py # run latest Python 2
py -3.3
py -2.7-32 # use 32-bit version
py # run default version
```

But if you want to completely get rid of the other version just uninstall and reinstall that other version....

Reminder: This is for Windows CLI only.

And like @Reez0 said, you should really look into using Virtual Environments.

Comment: I think this is Windows only. It is useful, but virtualenv is still better to manage python version and third-party package versions install combinations.

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned that, thanks for the reminder